# Deselect a selected area with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectable

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="folders block">
    <div class="ui-widget-content">            
         <table class="folders-list">
             <tbody class="folder">
                  <tr><td style="text-align: center">Папки: </td></tr>
                  <tr class="folder-name"><td><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><span>Всички</span></td></tr>          
             </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$(".folder").selectable({
    stop: function() {
        $(".ui-selected", this)
            .each(function() {
                var index = $("table tbody").index(this);   
            });     
    }
});
```

Everything is fine accept when I want to deselect the selected item. Wherever I click nothing happens. I didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Can you create a snippet or bin for this? Because, by default, you can deselect the selected.

Comment: I can deselect only if I click in the area of `<div class="folders block">` But I would like to deselect wherever I click

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is no straightforward way to do this, but you can use a trick.

When the user click on somewhere outside the container (`.folder`) you should do 2 things:

1. Remove the `.ui-selected` class of the selected items.
2. Clear the selected list of the widget's instance.

**Note:** It's a generic solution so maybe it will conflict with your other code (`$('html').click` for example) so be careful.

**To the code:**

```js
$( "#selectable" ).selectable().click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function(){
  var ins = $( "#selectable" ).selectable( "instance" );
  // clear the selected list
  ins.selectees = [];
  // remove the selected class
  ins.element.find('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
});
```

```css
#feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```